# Swiper slider - Blur up technique for loading images

Tags: javascript, css, image, swiper.js, intervention

I am using [iDangerous swiper](http://idangero.us/swiper/) for a slider that I have on my page.
But, since the images are loading very slowly I end up with the slider looking like this before the images are loaded, where only a thin line is shown, which is I assume the border of the image, like shown here in the image.

[image]

I assume that `imagecache` of [intervention image](http://image.intervention.io/) is contributing to the slow time of the image loading. This is the code for the slider, where I am implementing the default `swiper slider lazy loading`:

```
 @foreach($players as $player)
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <a href="/player/{{ $player->id }}/{{ $player->fullName }}">
          <div class="card bg-dark text-white">
            <img data-src="/imagecache/medium/{{ $player->image_filename }}" class="card-img swiper-lazy"/>
            <div class="swiper-lazy-preloader"></div>
            <div class="card-img-overlay">
              <div class="card-content">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{ $player->first_name }} {{ $player->last_name }}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">
                  {{ $player->nationality }}
                  @if($player->position != '')
                  | {{ $player->position }}
                  @endif
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    @endforeach
```

But, the spinner is not shown at first, it is only the line, since I assume I don't have the set height for the card image, this is the scss:

```
.card {
  border: 1px solid $gray-border;
}
.card-img {
  width: 100%;
}
.card-title {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  color: $white;
}
.card-text {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.card-image-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  img {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  }
}
.card-content {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.75rem;
  padding-top: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35), rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.65));
}
.card-img-overlay {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  align-items: flex-end;
  .play-icon-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 1rem);
    top: calc(50% - 1rem);
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    img {
      width: 40px;
    }
  }
}
.card-footer {
  padding: 0.75rem;
  background-color: $white;
  a {
    color: $black;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    font-weight: 500;
  }
}
.video-player-avatar {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 2px;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .play-icon-wrapper {
    top: 45%!important;
    width: 1.2rem;
    height: 1.2rem;
    left: calc(50% - 0.6rem);
    img {
      width: 30px;
    }
  }
}
```

But, if I set the height, then I lose the responsivness of the slider. What I would like to do is to implement the blur up technique that is used on many sites, where the small image is sized and blurred before the bigger image is loaded. But I am not sure how to implement this with swiper slider. Are there any solutions for that?

Comment: whats the size of your `<img>`?

Comment: I am setting the image size with imagecache filter to be 275*300px, and then the image is resized with swiper slider to fit it so that it is responsive, since I have 5 images on bigger screens, 4 on medium, and 2 on small.

Comment: I think [this](https://css-tricks.com/the-blur-up-technique-for-loading-background-images/) may help you out... in my case i just compressed the images to make them a bit faster but this is pretty cool too

Comment: Maybe take a look at [SQIP](https://github.com/technopagan/sqip), it makes very small SVG versions of your images that you can then switch out to the full size versions on load. Also, if your images are a fixed aspect ratio, then another helpful technique is to give them a % width and a VW-based height. This should keep the responsiveness, but it gives the browser at least something to work with in terms of knowing ahead of time what the image sizes will be.

Answer (score 0):

These should speed up your page loads a little:

1. Reduce the sizes of your slider images to the exact image size that is required.
2. Use a cdn to preload cache so that it doesnt have to load the same images every time. **WP Super Cache** is always a good solution too.
3. Try disabling plugins to see if anything is conflicting.

Can you provide the web address where the slider is for me to have a look?

Or maybe these could help! CSS to make an alpha layer:

**HTML**

```
<div class="background-1">
<div class="layer">
</div>
</div>
<div class="background-3">
<div class="layer">
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.background-1 {
  background:url('...image1.png');
  position: relative;
}

/* Lets leave the middle background alone */

.background-3 {
  background:url('...image3.png');
  position: relative;

.layer {
  background-color: rgba(248, 247, 216, 0.7); /*Red Green Blue Alpha */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Or add a blur to the image like so:

**HTML**

```
<div class="BlurMeBaby"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.BlurMeBaby {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background:url('...ImageToBlur.png') no-repeat center;
    background-size:cover;
    -webkit-filter: blur(13px);
    -moz-filter: blur(13px);
    -o-filter: blur(13px);
    -ms-filter: blur(13px);
    filter: blur(13px);
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Let me know how it goes.